# Let $f(x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}$ and let $g(x)=f^{-1} (x)$. Find $g’’’(0)$

Tags: derivatives

My method is extremely inefficient, but here it is

$$g(f(x))=x$$
$$g’(f(x)).f’(x)=1$$Differentiating wrt x multiple times

$$g’’’(f(x))(f’(x))^3 + (g’’(f(x)))(2f’(x))(f’’(x)) + g’’(f(x)).f’(x).f’’(x) + g’(f(x)).f’’’(x)=0$$

I may have made some computation errors in this, but I can’t seem to find any (I apologize if there are)

$f(x)=0$ at $x=0$
$$g’’’(0) +2 g’’(0) + g’’(0) +2g’(0)=0$$

How do I proceed from here? Is there a better way to approach this ?

Comment: if instead of $f(x)$ you take $-\log(1-x)$, you'll get the same result

Comment: what is the source of the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $$g(f(x))=x$$
$$\Rightarrow g'(f(x)).f'(x)=1$$
$$\Rightarrow g'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}$$
$$g''(f(x)).f'(x)=-\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow g''(f(x))=-\frac{f''(x)}{(f'(x))^3}$$
I'll let you differentiate once again.

Note that I have not combined any other function with $g'(f(x))$ It is done so that it restricts $g'(f(x))$ from popping up in the final $g'''(x)$ expression. Same goes with $g''(x)$.

***Spoilers***

> $$g'''(f(x)).f'(x)=-\frac{f'''(x).(f'(x))^3-3(f''(x))^2.(f'(x))^2}{(f'(x))^6}$$ $$g'''(f(x))=-\frac{f'''(x).(f'(x))^3-3(f''(x))^2.(f'(x))^2}{(f'(x))^7}$$

> $$f(x)=x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{4}+\frac{x^5}{5}$$ $$f'(x)=1+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5$$ $$f''(x)=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+5x^4$$ $$f'''(x)=2+6x+...$$

> To conclude with, substitute $0$ in the above four(as$ f(0)=0$) $$f(0)=0$$ $$f'(0)=1$$ $$f''(0)=1$$ $$f'''(0)=2$$  $$\therefore g'''(0)=-\frac{f'''(0).(f'(0))^3-3(f''(0))^2.(f'(0))^2}{(f'(0))^7}$$ $$g'''(0)=-\frac{2.1-3.1.1}{1}$$ $$\therefore g'''(0)=1$$ :)

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ is an infinite series, then

$$y=f(x)=x+x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4+.....=-\ln(1-x) \implies y=-\ln(1-x) $$ $$ \implies x=1-e^{-y} \implies x=f^{-1}(y)=1-e^{-y} \implies f^{-1}(x)= 1-e^{-x}=g(x).$$
Then $$g'(x)=e^{-x}, ~g''(x)=-e^{-x} \implies g'''(x)=e^{-x} \implies g'''(0)=1$$

Comment: i think we are asked to find $g'''(0$

Comment: and how can we say f(x)=ln(1-x)

Comment: @Quantum I think it’s the expansion of $\ln (1-x)$

Comment: agreed but in the original question it was not an infinirte series

Comment: @Quantum Oh yes I have now found $g'''(0)=1$, your $ f(x)$ is an infinite series which is well known as $x+x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4+x^5/5+......$

Comment: yes i know that , i didnt see that the question was edited initially it was not so,  sorry

Comment: In the question, it is not meant to be an infinite series though. However, your answer is correct so there might have been a typo in the source question. But can you please confirm it again, since it wasn’t a typo on my part

Comment: Then why dots were there !

Comment: I just added the dots in my question because I didn’t want to type the whole thing out. In the source problem, the whole expression was typed out, clearly terminating at $\frac{x^5}{5}$

Comment: @Aditya did you get the problem from vikas guptas book if so it was not a typo .I have the same book and the question given was not an infinite series

Comment: @Quantum I am not aware of that book, and I didn’t pick it up from there. I agree though, my question didn’t have an infinite series either

Comment: @Aditya i have found the value of g'''(0) if f(x) was terminating and it also is 1 so it may not be a typo

Comment: @Quantum how did you do it?

Comment: @Aditya by brute force

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial, OP's approach is correct. The complete solution is here:

$$f(x)=x+x^2/2+x^3/3+x^4/4+x^5/5 \implies f(0)=0, f'(0)=1,f''(0)=1,=f'''(0)=2,$$

$$y=f(x) \implies x=f^{-1}{y} \implies x=g(y), gf(x)=1 \implies  g'(f(x))f'(x)=1~~~~(1)$$
$$\implies g'(0)=1/f'(0)=1$$
D. (1) w.r.t. $x$, we get
$$(2)~~~ g''(f(x)(f'(x))^2+g'(f(x)) f''(x)=0 \implies g''(0)+g'(0)f''(0)=0 \implies g''(0)=-1.$$
D. (2) w.r.t. $x$, we get
$$g'''(f(x))(f'(x))^3+3g''(f(x)) f'(x) f''(x)+g'(f(x)) f'(x) f'''(x)=0 ```(3)$$
Using values of : $g(0),g'(0),g''(0),f'(0),f''(0), f'''(0)$ in above, we get
$$g'''(0) +3g''(0)+2g'(0)=0 \implies g'''(0)=3-2=1$$

Comment: @Aditya if $f(x)$ is the polynomial and not the series, you may see my new answer, Your approach itself is correct.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** $g(0)=0$ and
$$g' = \frac{1}{f' \circ g}$$

You deduce $g'(0)$ and $g''$, then $g''(0)$ and $g'''$, then finally $g'''(0)$.

Comment: Is there any easier way to solve this, because it is getting quite heavy at $g’’’(x)$